# Making HTML read js with require pattern

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, web-frontend

**Have:**

```
project
   |- consume_script.js
   |- index.html
```

**Need** index.html to be like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="consume_script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**

`consume_script.js` requires npm's 'kafka-node'. HTML

```
//consume_script.js
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
      Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
      client = new kafka.Client("127.0.0.1:2181"),
      consumer = new Consumer(...
...
```

**Got when opening `index.html`:**

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Most simple way to make HTML "accept" a require call on a script?
If possible, a solution proposal to this specific case.

Comment: using `require` in front-end dev requires you to use the [`requirejs`](http://requirejs.org) library. However, I suggest you take a look at [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/) that includes `requirejs`

Answer (score 0):

`require` is a node functionality, one way of importing a js code to be used in another, it's putting it in a script tag before the `<script src="consume_script.js"></script>`, it's not the best practice, but it might work at this case. If you really want to use require at frontend scripts, you can take a look at some node based cli as gulp.